# Getting a blank file when creating a bitmap from LinearLayout in Android

Tags: android, file, bitmap, save, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to capture a signature to a file. I "paint" the signature on a LinearLayout and I try to convert the layout to a bitmap and compress it to a file. The problem is that it keeps clearing the signature off the screen right before it saves the bitmap to the file, resulting in a blank file.

The xml code and java code are at http://zumbrun.org/android.

Thanks for any help that can be offered.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you grabbing the ImageCache of the `LinearLayout` and not the `signature` object? I suspect that is your problem.